# Python: Sample from multivariate normal with N means and same covariance matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distribution, normal-distribution

Suppose I want to sample 10 times from multiple normal distributions with the same covariance matrix (identity) but different means, which are stored as rows of the following matrix:

```
means = np.array([[1, 5, 2],
                  [6, 2, 7],
                  [1, 8, 2]])
```

How can I do that in the most efficient way possible (i.e. avoiding loops)

I tried like this:

```
scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(means, np.eye(2)).rvs(10)
```

and

```
np.random.multivariate_normal(means, np.eye(2))
```

But they throw an error saying mean should be 1D.

## Slow Example

```
import scipy
np.r_[[scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(means[i, :], np.eye(3)).rvs() for i in range(len(means))]]
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop, or, better, a list comprehension.

Comment: in this special case, isn't one sample is like adding this means matrix to a 3x3 normal N(0,1) matrix?

Comment: How about we start with - what shape of output do you expect?  Because it's not at all clear what you want to get out of this.

Comment: I've edited with a slow example!

Comment: I don't think the example works

Comment: Now it should work!

Answer (score 1):

Your covariance matrix indicate that the sample are independent. You can just sample them at once:

```
num_samples = 10
flat_means = means.ravel()

# build block covariance matrix
cov = np.eye(3)
block_cov = np.kron(np.eye(3), cov)

out = np.random.multivariate_normal(flat_means, cov=block_cov, size=num_samples)

out = out.reshape((-1,) + means.shape)
```

Comment: They are independent only cause this is a MWE. I want it to work with a full covariance matrix. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Euler_Salter use block matrix to construct the `9x9` covariance matrix.

Comment: But they won't be independent

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Surely though the introduction of all those extra entries will slow it down compared to a list comprehension?

Comment: It might when you draw small samples. But I bet it would be much faster when you need to draw more samples. Try with 1000 samples and you see that this would be hundred times faster.