# Python (numpy): generate multivariate random samples for different mean vectors at the same time?

Tags: python, numpy, random, normal-distribution

My problem is this: I have several mean vectors (evaluated from some mean-function) that are associated with the same covariance matrix. I now what to generate a multivariate normal sample for each such mean vector along with the covariance matrix (that is constant for all the samples).

My solution is to simply iterate (with a for-loop) over the mean vectors and generate the multivariate samples one by one. This works. However, this could be slow. So I am wondering if there is a way to have a collection of mean vectors (represented as matrix, most conveniently) as input to NumPy's  `numpy.random.multivariate_normal()` function?

Is there any other clever way to program this so that it runs fast? Other suggestions?

Comment: Closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252624/python-sample-from-multivariate-normal-with-n-means-and-same-covariance-matrix/65254222#65254222).

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Yes, I can add code, but @QuangHoang reference was spot on.